# XSLT to remove milliseconds from timestamp

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am attempting to write an XSLT stylesheet that removes the milliseconds from any timestamp in an XML form. My sample XML below is just a sample there could conceivably be any number of timestamps in the envelope. So I'm thinking I need to pattern match the timestamp and then transform it. I can use XSLT 2.0 The original message looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
    </soap:Header>
      <soap:Body>
        <Staging_Submit_Service xmlns="com.xxx"> 
            <u_From_Partner__c>Our Partner</u_From_Partner__c>
            <u_To_Partner__c>Us</u_To_Partner__c>
            <u_Partner_CI__c/>
            <u_Partner_ID__c>10051</u_Partner_ID__c>
            <u_Partner_Name__c>ROSEVILLE</u_Partner_Name__c>
            <u_Partner_Reported_Date__c>2016-07-26T17:38:28.746134Z</u_Partner_Reported_Date__c>
            <u_Partner_Status_Reason__c>Failure in System</u_Partner_Status_Reason__c>
            <u_Partner_Submit_Date__c>2016-07-25T18:11:23.5443Z</u_Partner_Submit_Date__c>
            <u_Partner_Priority__c>Low</u_Partner_Priority__c>
            <u_Partner_Service_Type>Event</u_Partner_Service_Type>
        </Staging_Submit_Service>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and my resulting xml needs to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">    
    </soap:Header><soap:Body>
        <Staging_Submit_Service xmlns="com.xxx"> 
            <u_From_Partner__c>Our Partner</u_From_Partner__c>
            <u_To_Partner__c>Us</u_To_Partner__c>
            <u_Partner_CI__c/>
            <u_Partner_ID__c>10051</u_Partner_ID__c>
            <u_Partner_Name__c>ROSEVILLE</u_Partner_Name__c>
            <u_Partner_Reported_Date__c>2016-07-26T17:38:28Z</u_Partner_Reported_Date__c>
            <u_Partner_Status_Reason__c>Failure in System</u_Partner_Status_Reason__c>
            <u_Partner_Submit_Date__c>2016-07-25T18:11:23Z</u_Partner_Submit_Date__c>
            <u_Partner_Priority__c>Low</u_Partner_Priority__c>
            <u_Partner_Service_Type>Event</u_Partner_Service_Type>
        </Staging_Submit_Service>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Notice the timestamps. I started down this path but it doesn't seem to be getting me where I need to be.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns1="java:com.verizon.webservices.adapter.clecclient">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"  />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()"
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
      <xsl:value-of select='matches(.,".*[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}.*:[0-9]\{2\}*")'/>
    <xsl:value-of select='replace(., "s/.*[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}.*:[0-9]\{2\}\(\.[0-9]*\).*/\1","")'/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am really only vaguely familiar with XSLT and this particular problem requires me to use it.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments it seems that you can only use an XSLT 1.0 solution.

Here is one:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:df="com.xxx">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="df:u_Partner_Reported_Date__c/text()
                      |df:u_Partner_Submit_Date__c/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(.,'.'), 'Z')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
    </soap:Header>
      <soap:Body>
        <Staging_Submit_Service xmlns="com.xxx"> 
            <u_From_Partner__c>Our Partner</u_From_Partner__c>
            <u_To_Partner__c>Us</u_To_Partner__c>
            <u_Partner_CI__c/>
            <u_Partner_ID__c>10051</u_Partner_ID__c>
            <u_Partner_Name__c>ROSEVILLE</u_Partner_Name__c>
            <u_Partner_Reported_Date__c>2016-07-26T17:38:28.746134Z</u_Partner_Reported_Date__c>
            <u_Partner_Status_Reason__c>Failure in System</u_Partner_Status_Reason__c>
            <u_Partner_Submit_Date__c>2016-07-25T18:11:23.5443Z</u_Partner_Submit_Date__c>
            <u_Partner_Priority__c>Low</u_Partner_Priority__c>
            <u_Partner_Service_Type>Event</u_Partner_Service_Type>
        </Staging_Submit_Service>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header> 
    </soap:Header>
      <soap:Body>
        <Staging_Submit_Service xmlns="com.xxx"> 
            <u_From_Partner__c>Our Partner</u_From_Partner__c>
            <u_To_Partner__c>Us</u_To_Partner__c>
            <u_Partner_CI__c/>
            <u_Partner_ID__c>10051</u_Partner_ID__c>
            <u_Partner_Name__c>ROSEVILLE</u_Partner_Name__c>
            <u_Partner_Reported_Date__c>2016-07-26T17:38:28Z</u_Partner_Reported_Date__c>
            <u_Partner_Status_Reason__c>Failure in System</u_Partner_Status_Reason__c>
            <u_Partner_Submit_Date__c>2016-07-25T18:11:23Z</u_Partner_Submit_Date__c>
            <u_Partner_Priority__c>Low</u_Partner_Priority__c>
            <u_Partner_Service_Type>Event</u_Partner_Service_Type>
        </Staging_Submit_Service>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*) and . castable as xs:dateTime]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(., '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

plus your first template.

So the complete stylesheet is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*) and . castable as xs:dateTime]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(., '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actually the above seems to not preserve any timezone suffix present and ensuring it is output as `Z` if it is UTC is a bit tricky, but I think if you make the `value-of`

```
        <xsl:value-of select="if (timezone-from-dateTime(.) eq xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0H')) then format-dateTime(., '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]Z') else format-dateTime(., '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01][Z]')"/>
```

then it works fine.

It seems the problem about the timezone `Z` was resolved in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#rules-for-datetime-formatting to allow

```
        <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(., '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01][Z00:00t]')"/>
```

but I have not tested whether that works with XmlPrime or processors other than Saxon.

The following works for me with Xalan inside Oxygen as far as identifying the two elements with dateTimes in your input sample and reformatting them to remove the decimals of the seconds:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs date" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*) and string-length() > 19 and date:date() != '']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="date:format-date(date:date(.), &quot;yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ&quot;)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However the created output dates differ, the input `<u_Partner_Reported_Date__c>2016-07-26T17:38:28.746134Z</u_Partner_Reported_Date__c>` shows up as `<u_Partner_Reported_Date__c>2016-07-25T22:00:00+0000</u_Partner_Reported_Date__c>`, so either the date parsing or formatting is broken.

Comment: This worked great in my tester but it erred when attempting to use it in the appliance. My guess is different xml parsers:

Comment: My guess is different xml parsers: I am receiving the error:    ERROR:  'Syntax error in '*[not(*) and . castable as xs:dateTime]'.'
FATAL ERROR:  'com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.NotCall cannot be cast to com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Pattern'
           :com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.NotCall cannot be cast to com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Pattern.     Any chance of trying a different match pattern?

Comment: If you want to use XSLT 2.0 in the Java world then you need to use Saxon 9 from Saxonica, Xalan is an XSLT 1.0 processor and does neither support the `xs:dateTime` data type nor the XPath 2.0 `castable as` expression nor the `format-dateTime` nor the `matches` or `replace` function you tried to use.

Comment: Thank you. I just went back read into the documentation and although the appliance support XSLT 2.0 the filter that does XSLT transformation only supports XSLT 1.0. Grrrrr... So that leaves me to find a match statement that will match a DateTime in the above format using XSLT 1.0. So back to the drawing board. Could anyone help with that?

Comment: According to http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions_xsltc.html#exslt_ext and http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xalan/lib/ExsltDatetime.html there is EXSLT date/time support so you will have to check whether you can bake something using those functions.